# How to upgrade selenium from version 3.14 to 4?

Tags: qaf

Description:
The current version of selenium is 3.14 if I want to upgrade to 4, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of qaf you are using? If you are using latest version of qaf you can use selenium4. Refer [announcement](https://groups.google.com/g/qaf-users/c/AiMG53M2Xy4/m/jfczaw1BBQAJ) in users group. As of today latest [release](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf/releases) of qaf is 3.1.0

Comment: I use this project

https://github.com/Perfecto-Quantum/Quantum-Starter-Kit

it use 3.0.0 now, could you kindly help to tell me how to upgrade qaf in this project? and upgrade the selenium?

Comment: You should try adding/updating qaf 3.1.0 and selenium-java 4.x dependency in your pom. AFAIK quantum supports latest version of qaf, but If it doesn't work check with perfecto support team.